# This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am getting the below problem in drupal6 when writing php redirect.

This is the problem:

> The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

I have written code like:

```
global $base_url,$user;
$uid = $user->uid;

$msg = "Please select your user type (capital provider or project sponsor) and agree to the terms and conditions. Then, you’ll be able to post and find capital or a project in which to invest.";

$url =  $base_url."/editProfile?message=".$msg;

header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Do you put that code in a global file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if the current page is the same as the page you want to redirect to.

```
if (getCurrentPage() == "editProfile" && getCurrentMessage() == $msg) // THEN DO NOT REDIRECT
```